# I need to create a feature in the Swift app where the user enters his/her Instagram login and the profile feed is shown. Is it possible?

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, instagram-api

I’m making an app in Swift and don’t really know where to start solving this problem. I’ve looked at the Instagram API, but it seems that I can do that only by logging in the user in Instagram. Is there any way to avoid the password entrering? Just tapping the account name and then approaching to the profile feed.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think, Instagram doesn't provide any API to get the feeds for any user. So you can't do it.

Answer (score 0):

I did this a while ago, you need to read and following the documentation from https://www.instagram.com/developer/.

Basically register your app, let the user login using their credentials and then once you're authenticated you can query instagram's API and do most actions you can do if you were using the Instagram app (like, share, post etc)